# jQuery: If character limit is "x" do "this"?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set a class on a div where there's text inside, but I would like to add a class only if there's a character count of 60.

So something like, "if character count = 60 {" and then I'll add the class. Is this possible?

Comment: [`keyup` event handler](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) on your field, check length of field, [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addclass/) if >= 60, [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) if not. **Edit** if it's not an input field, just run your if and those class functions without the event handler- [**here's a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/scrowler/3gLUz/)

Comment: @scrowler I would also suggest in addition to `keyup` think about `keydown` just in case someone holds a character down. This would only be necessary if the function that runs is *necessary* for the page/input to work properly. Just a thought.

Comment: keyup would fire when the key is released, regardless of how long it is held for..

Comment: @scrowler Yes, but if it's necessary for function to run immediately after 60 characters are added and I hold down a key your function won't run until I release it which could be at 500 characters. It's just a suggestion & also that's what I mean by "*necessary*".

Comment: Gotcha - good thinking

Comment: It's not an input field. The question says it's a div.

Answer (score 6):

Can use jQuery `filter()` :

```
$(selector).filter(function(){
   return $(this).text().length >= 60; 
}).addClass('someClass');
```

`filter()` will reduce the elements defined in selector to subset ( or none) that match conditions returned from the callback

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3gLUz/2/)**</kbd>